# List<> - Reflection

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to determine if a list contains a object, if it does then run a method to clear the original list (in a singleton class), then repopulate the list minus the one I ran the condition over.

```
public void removeSelectedItem(Object obj){
    SearchBuilder builder = SearchBuilder.getInstance();
    try {
        String methodName = labelToMethod.get(getTitle());
        if( methodName == null ){
            methodName = getTitle().replace(" ","");
        }
        Method m = builder.getClass().getMethod("get"+methodName);
        Object r = m.invoke(builder);
        if( r != null ){
            if( r instanceof Integer ){
                if( ((Integer) r).intValue() == ((Integer) obj).intValue() ) {
                    setSelectedItem(null);
                }
            } else if ( r instanceof String ){
                if(r.equals(obj)) {
                    setSelectedItem(null);
                }
            } else if ( r instanceof ArrayList ){
                Log.d("TEST",((ArrayList) r).size()+"");
                if( ((ArrayList) r).contains(obj) ){
                    Log.d("TEST", "R CONTAINS OBJ");
                    Log.d("TEST", "BEFORE: " + ((ArrayList) r).size() + "");
                    clearSelectedItem();
                    Log.d("TEST","AFTER: " + ((ArrayList) r).size() + "");
                    for ( int i = 0; i < ((ArrayList) r).size(); i++ ){
                        Log.d("TEST","IN FOR LOOP" + i);
                        if( !((ArrayList) r).get(i).equals(obj) ){
                            Log.d("TEST", "SETTING VALUES");
                            setSelectedItem(((ArrayList) r).get(i));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The clearSelectedItem method is:

```
    public void clearSelectedItem(){
    SearchBuilder builder = SearchBuilder.getInstance();
    try {
        String methodName = labelToMethod.get(getTitle());
        if( methodName == null ){
            methodName = getTitle().replace(" ","");
        }
        Method m = builder.getClass().getMethod("clear"+methodName);
        m.invoke(builder);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
D/TEST :  2
D/TEST :  R CONTAINS OBJ
D/TEST :  BEFORE: 2
D/TEST :  AFTER: 0
```

So it's not entering the loop, as the ArrayList size has been reduced to 0. But what I don't understand is, why has the ArrayList been reduced? Surely the object has been set as part of the m.invoke call earlier in the removeSelectedItem method, and the clearSelectedItem doesn't touch this response?

I'm rather new to Java, so any insight would be great!

EDIT:
So I've managed to solve my problem, but would still really like some insight into what's going on...

I've solved it by cloning the ArrayList:

```
                } else if ( r instanceof ArrayList ){
                Object c = ((ArrayList) r).clone();
                if( ((ArrayList) c).contains(obj) ){
                    clearSelectedItem();
                    for ( int i = 0; i < ((ArrayList) c).size(); i++ ){
                        if( !((ArrayList) c).get(i).equals(obj) ){
                            setSelectedItem(((ArrayList) c).get(i));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: You are calling the 'get' method not the 'set' method at `Object r = m.invoke(builder);`.

Comment: Yes that's expected. The get method is used to get the original selected items which the removeSelectedItem function loops over and then resets the values via the setSelectedItem() method.

Comment: What is `SearchBuilder`?

Comment: SearchBuilder is a singleton class used to store search criteria. It's irrelevant for the question though. The issue is that the value of r.size() changes from before clearSelectedItems, and after.

Comment: `it's irrelevant for the question` no, it is not. your list `r` comes from `builder.getSomething()`, and your list is emptied when you call `builder.clearSomething()`. Clearly that's where the list is cleared.

Comment: That's correct. But by that stage `r` is an `ArrayList` containing the values. So why when I interrogate that list (which should already be defined) after clearing the super list in builder does my already defined list also get cleared?

Comment: It's like `r` is just a reference to the `ArrayList` in `SearchBuilder`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a little more research, Java is pass-by-value, which means that it passes the reference to the `ArrayList`, rather than create a new `ArrayList` with the same values. Amending `Object r` in any way affects the original ArrayList in `SearchBuilder` itself.

http://www.javaranch.com/campfire/StoryPassBy.jsp

Answer (score 0):

So I dont understand why you are repopulating the list itself, 
would it be much cleaner or neat if you just use

```
    if(list.contain(object))
    {
       list.remove(object);
    }
```

or if you want to remove all of them just use

```
      while(list.contain(object))
      {
      list.remove(object);
      }
```